# Finding all sym links that reach into a specific folder

Tags: linux, unix, command-line, symlink

So, I realize find has a  -samefile flag, so someone can do something like: `find -L / -samefile /path/to/some/file`

However, I've got a machine here that has sym links everywhere, some of which reach into a specific folder:

`/etc/supervisor -> /home/deploy/live/etc/supervisor
/etc/nginx -> /home/deploy/live/etc/nginx
/some/other/path -> /home/deploy/live/testing/things`

How can I find all sym links that point to something within `/home/deploy/live`? Can I find all sym links, then filter?

All help appreciated!

Comment: This is off-topic for SO as it is not about programming; it should be on [su]. Flagged for migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
find / -type l -printf "%p -> %l\n"|grep "-> /home/deploy/live"
```